# SilverLight: game programming for kids

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible for kids with only HTML/CSS programming experience to do game programming in SilverLight 4.0?

They are using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express edition.

Do they have to learn c# or any other language since they are just starting out?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question but perhaps CW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What age range are you talking about? I imagine if you had really smart kids, they could pick-up SilverLight 4.0, but yes, learning C# for the logic and XAML for the GUI would be required.

Ergo, my recommendation is to skip SilverLight given your requirements.

Instead, you should [try Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) which is a programming language designed for kids. It's very visually based and introduces the basic concepts of programming yet allows them to create their own games with ease.

Comment: +1, Thats a real gem, finally something that my kids can grasp yet actually uses concepts that are in real world programming.

Comment: ...albeit a programming environment that is recently banned on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that Silverlight (and infact HTML/Javascript) would be difficult for children to grasp and easily produce a game without getting bored and frustrated.

You could try [Kodu](http://fuse.microsoft.com/kodu.html) as a possible alternative:

> Kodu is a visual programming language
>   made specifically for creating games.
>   It is designed to be accessible for
>   children and enjoyable for anyone.
>
> Kodu provides an end-to-end creative
>   environment for designing, building,
>   and playing your own new games. The
>   core of the Kodu project is the
>   programming user interface. The
>   language is simple and entirely
>   icon-based. Programs are composed of
>   pages, which are broken down into
>   rules, which are further divided into
>   conditions and actions. Conditions are
>   evaluated simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets start that - HTML / CSS is not programming. There is no logic in there that requires programming, so ANY programming is a totalyl different area an they will have to get started at point 0. If you would have javascript in the HTML/CSS side that would be different.

C# would be required - Silverlight backend is done in C#. Quite a lot is required. C# for logic, XAML for the UI, including the powerfull mechanisms for databinding etc. Not a totally easy starter, but as a nice side course it could work.

Answer (score 0):

They will have to learn C#, yes. You can do a lot of the visuals using the XAML declarative markup, but the logic will be driven by C# code.